# How can i set custom pushpin and infobox in clustering map in V8 Module

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

In V7 Bing map you have provided functionality of custmally add pushpin and  infobox  in clustering map  on below link

https://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#LoadingDynamicModule3

But in V8 bing map Microsoft didn't provided how can i set Pushpin and infobox in clustering map .

http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#clusteringMeanAverage+TS

Can you please provide sample code for pushpin and info box in clustering map ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to store data with a pushpin using the metadata property and add a click event to the pushpin that opens an infobox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript' 
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' 
            async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map, infobox;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
        });

        //Create an infobox at the center of the map but don't show it.
        infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
            visible: false
        });

        //Assign the infobox to a map instance.
        infobox.setMap(map);

        //Create a pushpin in the at a random location in the map bounds.
        var randomLocation = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getLocations(1, map.getBounds());
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(randomLocation);

        //Store some metadata with the pushpin.
        pin.metadata = {
            title: 'Pin Title',
            description: 'Pin discription'
        };

        //Add an click event handler to the pushpin.
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', pushpinClicked);

        //Add pushpin to the map.
        map.entities.push(pin);
    }

    function pushpinClicked(e) {
        //Make sure the infobox has metadata to display.
        if (e.target.metadata) {
            //Set the infobox options with the metadata of the pushpin.
            infobox.setOptions({
                location: e.target.getLocation(),
                title: e.target.metadata.title,
                description: e.target.metadata.description,
                visible: true
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: rbrundritt !!  I want to open info box in clustering map i had this code but raised issue . can you give me code for open info box on each pin in clustering map with html customizable infobox . i  have to set multiple info box  on each pin .

Comment: Opening an infobox for a clustered pushpins is the same process as opening an infobox for a standard pushpin. Only difference is that in the callback handler for customizing the cluster pushpin, you add your metadata nd click event there. To customize the HTML of the infobox you can do that in the pushpinClicked function.

Answer (score 1):

For individual pushpins you can customize them before you add them to the clustering layer and the clustering layer will simply render them. No need for a callback like in the old v7 module. A callback is still used when customizing clustered pushpins.

For infoboxes simply add a click event to the pushpins and clusters and when the event fires you can load an infobox. This is really simply. Also, you only need one infobox in an app and simply update it's content based on what has been clicked.

Full documentation can also be found here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx

Comment: How can i  dynamically set info box of each location in module v8?

Comment: Easily, add metadata to your pushpin like pin.metadata = { your data }; then add click handlers to your pushpins. In the click event handler set the title and description values of an infobox. Here is a V7 code example that shows how to do this (works in V8 too): https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/ This uses a single infobox for all the pushpins which provides good performance as there is only DOM elements for one infobox that the page needs to track/update as the map moves.

Comment: can you please provide code  ? i tried but not able to .